# Not able to connect to Websockets on Heroku

Tags: angularjs, node.js, heroku, laravel-5, websocket

I have been working on an PHP Laravel Application for which I have been using Redis and Node.JS to get connected to the WebSocket.

So in order to achieve that I have been trying to run the node server on port 3000 but heroku is dynamically allocating the port.

Because of this I am unable to get the correct port no on client side.

What should I do in order to fix it ?

Client side config :

```
var socket = io.connect('http://app-around.herokuapp.com:3000');
  Note: Host Name is app-around.herokuapp.com
```

Backend is Running Fine as shown below:

```
    C:\xampp\htdocs\around-us>heroku run node socket.jsRunning node 
   socket.js on app-around... up, run.5567 (Free)
    // Randomly generated port number it is..

   Message Recieved: {"event":"App\\Events\\NewMessage","data":{"data":
    {"message":"Question Posted"}},"socket":null}
```

So events are getting generated on the Server side but am not able to receive them on the client side. Tried several things on Front End but none of them is working:

```
    Eg: 1) var socket = io.connect();
        2) var socket = io.connect(window.location.hostname);
```

Node Server Code:

```
      var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var Redis = require('ioredis');
var redis = require('redis').createClient(process.env.REDIS_URL);

redis.subscribe('test-channel', function(err, count) {

});

redis.on('message', function(channel, message) {
   console.log('Message Recieved: ' + message);

    message = JSON.parse(message);

    io.emit(channel + ':' + message.event, message.data);

     var temp = "data";
    io.emit("time", temp);

});

var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

http.listen(port, function(){
    console.log('Listening on Port 23000');
});
```

JS Code for the Angular app on the front end side:

```
var socket = io();

    socket.on("time",function(data){
            alert(data);
    });
```

Comment: Drop the port number when you're connecting remotely to Heroku - the network routing layer will take care to forward HTTP (port 80) and HTTPS (port 443) to the dynamically allocated port.

Answer (score 3):

In Node you should get the port from env vars:

```
server.listen(+process.env.PORT || 3000, () => {
    Logger.info(`Listening on port ${process.env.PORT || 3000}...`);
});
```

and in your io client you don't need to specify the port number:

`io.connect('http://app-around.herokuapp.com')`

Comment: @HoneyThakuria Can you share your socketIO server?

Comment: @HoneyThakuria are you serving socketIO client from `http://app-around.herokuapp.com/socket.io/socket.io.js`?

Comment: I have been using <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.7.3/socket.io.js"></script>

Comment: Try using `<script type="text/javascript" src="/socket.io/socket.io.js></script>`. It would be helpful if you can share your node server and how are you using socket with redis.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Andrés, **the Server** should collect the port from the environment:

The development environment won't have a `PORT` variable, so we add a default port (you're using `3000`, which is common enough).

```
  process.env.PORT || 3000
```

**The Client** - and I'm assuming a browser - should be able to automatically identify the target server using the HTTP URL address and connect to the correct Websocket URL and port.

I use a variation on the following code when I don't use a pre-made library (libraries often have their own URL schemes):

```
// websocket connects to root ("/")
var ws_url =
    document.location.origin.replace(/^http/i, "ws");
// OR web socket connects to full URL path (i.e. "/my/path")
var ws_url =
    document.location.href.replace(/^http/i, "ws");
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess issue is on your client side 
var socket = io.connect('http://app-around.herokuapp.com');
try this or
var socket=io.connect();
I hope it will help you